# Loop or apply functions to run an equation with different variables

Tags: r, loops, apply, repeat

I am trying to do something that I am sure is really simple in R. But I cannot figure it out. I want to run the same equation 6 times, changing the variables within the equation each time. 
My data is something like this:

```
[#Rename my data
mydata <- BSC_OnlineSurvey_Salient.Beliefs
summary (mydata)
View(mydata)

##Descriptive stats
sapply(mydata, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
sumstats <- sapply(mydata, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
sumstats

#1st: Rename columns
colnames (mydata)
colnames(mydata)=c("ID", "Understands restocking", "Restocking will increase the No. of crabs", "Increasing the No. of crabs is...", "Restocking will result in more crabs to catch", "More crabs to catch is...", "Restocking will result in more fishers fishing for crabs", "More fishers fishing for crabs is...", "Resocking will result in no change in abundance of crabs", "No change in the abundance of crabs is...","Restocking will increase the fishing pressure on crabs", "Increasing the fishing pressure on crabs is", "Restocking will have an impact on the environment and other species", "Having an impact on the environment and other species is...", "Overall views on restocking") 
View(mydata)

#Replace Belief evaluation (very unlikely to very likely) from -3-3 to 0-6
Eval1 <- mydata$`Restocking will increase the No. of crabs`
...#Done for 6 "Eval"
Eval1
Eval1\[Eval1 == 3\] <- 6
Eval1\[Eval1 == 2\] <- 5
Eval1\[Eval1 == 1\] <- 4
Eval1\[Eval1 == 0\] <- 3
Eval1\[Eval1 == -3\] <- 0
Eval1\[Eval1 == -2\] <- 1
Eval1\[Eval1 == -1\] <- 2

...
Strength1 <- mydata$`Increasing the No. of crabs is...`
Strength2 <- mydata$`More crabs to catch is...`
Strength3 <- mydata$`More fishers fishing for crabs is...`
...#Done for 6 "Strength"][1]
```

I do not want to write 6 times the same simple equation. I cannot figure out how to do it, I just have a slight idea that it is probably using one of the apply f(x) or making a loop...

My data`[Is a set of variables, Eval(1,2,3...) are on a scale from -3 to 3; Strength (1,2,3,..) are on a scale from 0 to 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G43OY.png)

I want to do the cross product of for each row, and then get the mean for each cross products:
Eval1*Strength1
Eval2*Strength2

Ideally without writting
crossprod1 <- mean(Eval1*Strength1, na.rm=TRUE)
crossprod1

If anyone could help with this I would really appreciate it!
Cheers!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH9Zs.png
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample of your data in the question itself, something like the ouput of `dput(head(<you dataset name>,10))` should do. (And if you can try to format a little more code and list in your post that would be great, guide is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Comment: Is that clearer? I am new with this so I am capable of not being helpful at all unintentionally...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this gives you some ideas. Cheers!

```
meanTotals = c()
for(r in 1:nrow(dataset)){
  rowTotals = c()
  for(c in 1:ncol(dataset)/2){
    rowTotals = c(rowTotals, dataset[r, 2*c-1] * dataset[r, 2*c])
  }
  meanTotals = c(meanTotals, rowTotals)
}
mean(meanTotals)
```

Comment: Aww please don't grow a vector in a loop, that's a copy per iteration, you can compute the resulting size, allocate it before the loop